# Symfony ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: php, symfony, redirect

If I call / and am not logged in, I get the error ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.
Actually, I should be redirected to the login page. Where’s the mistake?

security.yaml:

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        lazy: true
        provider: app_user_provider
        logout:
            path: app_logout
        form_login:
            login_path: app_login
            check_path: app_login


access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_USER:  ROLE_USER
    ROLE_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
```

Controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/{id}",defaults={"id" = null} , name="app_dashboard")
 */
public function index(PositiveTimeRepository $positiveTimeRepository, $id): Response
{

    return $this->render('dashboard/index.html.twig', [
        'positiveData' => $positiveTimeRepository->findBy([
            'user' => $this->getUser()]),
        'issetGetID' => $id
    ]);
}
```

SecurityController:

```
/**
 * @Route("/login", name="app_login")
 */
public function login(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils): Response
{
    
    $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

    
    $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

    return $this->render('login/login.html.twig', [
        'last_username' => $lastUsername,
        'error' => $error
    ]);
}
```

I updated my controllers and security.yaml

Comment: `/` in your *access_control* means anything after `/` will also be *ROLE_USER*. Try removing `- { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }` in your *access_control* and it should work.

Comment: Ok, I removed it but it doesn't work. `firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            lazy: true
            provider: app_user_provider
            logout:
                path: app_logout
            form_login:
                login_path: app_login
                check_path: app_login


    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }`

Comment: It looks like the controller priority, the `/{id}` will be hit first and set to `login` as it will match that route instead of your `/login`. Try adding `priority=10` to your login controller like the docs [here](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-1-route-annotations-priority)

Comment: @Bossman But do you know why my other routes like logout, userlist doesn't work anymore? Only if I remove {id} in my app_dashboard it works

Comment: Will be the same issue, routes in your controllers are loaded in order, so `/{id}` route will always match first with anything after `/` even `/userlist`. Personally I would remove the `{id}` and just use somthing like `$id = $request->get('id');` in the controller, so that would be set like `domain.com/?id=99`

Comment: I solved the problem with: 
`/**
     * @Route("/{id<\d+>?}", name="app_dashboard")
     */`

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You don’t have to check for the roles in your controller yourself the security package does that with the firewall you defined, but you would have to define your login url:

```
firewalls:
    main:
        # ...
        form_login:
            # "login" is the name of the route created previously
            login_path: login
            check_path: login
```

Comment: I forgot to send those lines. I did, however, put the lines in my code. I removed the check lines in my controller.

I have noticed that if I remove {id}, I successfully go to the login page. But I need {id}